# C# Get Path/Filename by Handle (hWnd) 32 and 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, path, 64-bit, filenames

I got the following code to get path/filename by handle:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out uint processId);

    public static string GetProcessPath(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        uint pid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
        return proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
    }
```

it works perfect in 32 bit but I get error in 64bit > "Only part of the ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed."
the project is compiled as x86 (platform target x86).

How can I fix it?

~Thanks Ron

Comment: Hm... which line is the error in?

Comment: return proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();

Comment: Try running your program as administrator.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I am already running it as administrator. this is not the problem.

@Cody Gray, I have no idea. I didnt build this function, but even when I change it to IntPtr it doest work.  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out IntPtr processId);

public static string GetProcessPath(IntPtr hwnd)
{
 IntPtr pid = IntPtr.Zero;
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
 Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid.ToInt32());
 return proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from your question that you've currently compiled your program as a 32-bit application. However, the process you're trying to query (assuming you're running on a 64-bit version of Windows) is undoubtedly a 64-bit one. [That kind of thing isn't allowed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx). Although you can run 32-bit applications on 64-bit versions of Windows, they run under the dedicated Windows on Windows (WOW64) subsystem. That's why you're getting a `Win32Exception` claiming that "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed". I agree it's not the most descriptive of error messages if you don't already know how Windows manages 32-bit and 64-bit processes, but armed with this knowledge it makes at least a little more sense.

**The solution is to compile your application as a 64-bit application (x64), or for "Any CPU".** Everything should work as expected after that. If possible, I suggest using "Any CPU", which will allow the application to run in 32-bit mode on 32-bit OSes and 64-bit on 64-bit OSes. Which is really the ideal set of circumstances, assuming that:

1. You've written your P/Invoke definitions correctly (i.e., using `IntPtr` where appropriate, instead of `Integer`).
2. You're not relying on 3rd-party DLLs (to which you don't have the source code) that were compiled as 32-bit.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I've just wrote a sample WinForms application using this code, compiled against x86 and it worked perfectly fine on my Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @Darin: Which process are you interrogating? That could be the pivotal issue. It's not clear from the question if the asker is passing a window handle for his application (which wouldn't make a lot of sense; there are much better ways to get this information for the current application), or some other process on the system.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, If you used this function to extract the path of the exe you are using it will work. but if you'll try to extract path of another exe it will throw u this error.

Comment: @Cody, the hosting process. You are correct. I will try with other processes.

Comment: @Ron: If you've already proven that to be the case, then I have even more confidence in my answer. Is there a particular reason you'd prefer to compile this as a 32-bit app?

Comment: @Cody Gray, Yes I do.. the program I am working on should be both for 32 and 64 so thats the reason I use x86..

Comment: @Ron: Then the "Any CPU" option should be acceptable. Compiled this way, the application will run in 32-bit mode on 32-bit OSes and 64-bit on 64-bit OSes. Which is really the ideal set of circumstances, assuming that 1) you've written your P/Invoke definitions correctly (i.e., using `IntPtr` instead of `Integer`), and 2) you're not relying on 3rd-party DLLs that were written assuming 32-bit code.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I am not relaying on 3rd-patry DLLs but I am relaying on 3rd-party class that was written for 32bit, therefore I cannot use the "Any CPU" option. do you have any other solution?

Comment: @Ron: Is that 3rd-party class provided by a satellite DLL, or is it code that you've placed in your project? If you have the source, it's a simple matter of recompiling it to 64-bit as well. It's fairly unlikely it will have any compatibility problems compiled for "Any CPU" unless it does a lot of heavy P/Invoke (and even then, those problems are quite fixable). Normal managed code written in .NET is very portable. But no, I don't know of any other solution.

Comment: @Cody Gray, sorry, I didnt notice. I am relaying on 3rd-party DLLs > Skybound.VisualStyles.dll and AMS.Profile.dll. Anyway thank you for trying.

Comment: @Cody Gray, This is edit to the previous comment. I couldnt edit because more than 5 minutes passed. I deleted the Skybound.VisualStyles dll and compiled as "Any CPU" it worked. thank you.

Comment: @Ron: I'm glad to hear you got it working. I'm not much of a "themes" guy, but from what I can tell on their website, that library is intended to fix bugs that have mostly been fixed already by later versions of the .NET Framework. And those that haven't appear to be trivial to fix with some P/Invoke (see related questions here on SO). So you shouldn't be losing much with removing that dependency. Not to mention, most reputable companies provide DLLs compiled for "Any CPU"—it's worth investigating if it matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a known problem with this, it smells environmental.  The error is very low level, probably the wow64 emulation layer.  I can only suggest you punt and use a different way to get the same info.  You can use WMI, [Win32_Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Run a select query on ProcessId, the ExecutablePath property gives you what you are looking for.  Use the W[MI Code Creator utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) to experiment, it auto-generates the C# code you need.  The odds are however not zero that this will fail the same way.

Comment: WMI is an intensive lookup, should be avoided wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

It works well for me on a 64x machine. The only changes to the code are checking the values, as:

```
if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    if (pid != 0) 
    {
        var p = Process.GetProcessById((int) pid)
        if (p != null)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This thing is absolutely possible from a 32 bit application when checking a 64 bit process, though not as straightforward as it would be if it were a 64 bit compiled application:

```
    [Flags]
    enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VMOperation = 0x00000008,
        VMRead = 0x00000010,
        VMWrite = 0x00000020,
        DupHandle = 0x00000040,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000,
        ReadControl = 0x00020000,
        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hprocess, int dwFlags, StringBuilder lpExeName, out int size);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

    private static Process GetProcessByHandle(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        try
        {
            uint processID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processID);
            return Process.GetProcessById((int)processID);
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }

    private static string GetExecutablePathAboveVista(int ProcessId)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
        IntPtr hprocess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
                                      false, ProcessId);
        if (hprocess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = buffer.Capacity;
                if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, buffer, out size))
                {
                    return buffer.ToString();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hprocess);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static string GetWindowPath(IntPtr hwind)
    {
        try
        {
            Process currentProcess = GetProcessByHandle(hwind);

            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
            {
                string newMethReturn = GetExecutablePathAboveVista(currentProcess.Id);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newMethReturn))
                    return newMethReturn;
            }


            if (currentProcess != null)

                return currentProcess.MainModule.FileName;
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch
        { return null; }
    }
```

Comment: 3 years late to the party but wanted to say thanks, been having a very hard time finding a way to gracefully stop a process I'm wrapping, this proved to be the last piece to the puzzle as I needed a way to discern between two windows with the same title - but not executable paths.