# C# Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed during Process.Kill()

Tags: c#, exception, process

I have been researching this issue pretty extensively and cannot seem to find an answer.

I know that the `Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed` exception is thrown when a 32-bit process tries to access a 64-bit process and the same for a 64-bit modifying a 32-bit process.

The solution to that issue is to change the Platform Target to 'Any CPU'. I have tried this and unfortunately this does not solve my issue.

The next block of code is what keeps throwing the exception. The program that runs this code is used to open up applications on remote computers and keeps a list of all the processes that the program itself opened so that I don't have to loop through all the processes.

```
Process processToRemove = null;
lock (_runningProcesses)
{
    foreach (Process p in _runningProcesses)
    {
        foreach (ProcessModule module in p.Modules)
        {
            string[] strs = text.Split('\\');

            if (module.ModuleName.Equals(strs[strs.Length - 1]))
            {
                processToRemove = p;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (processToRemove != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (processToRemove != null)
    {
        processToRemove.Kill();
        _runningProcesses.Remove(processToRemove);
    }
}
```

These processes can and most likely will be 32-bit and 64-bit, mixed together.

Is there anything I am doing that I shouldn't be doing, or is there just a better way to do all of this?

Comment: I don't know your whole program but since you seem to have the rights to remote kill, have you considered using PowerShell and remote kill it ? you can even call cmdlets from c# if necessary. http://4sysops.com/archives/query-and-kill-a-process-on-a-remote-computer-using-powershell-and-wmi/

Comment: @Vincent: This is the way that it works. I have a "Server" program that I run on a computer and all the computers in the same room are "clients" of this server computer. All the clients run a client program which accept TCP messages. To close a program, I send the client a TCP message to close a certain process and the client handles the killing of its own programs.

Comment: It may work. I can't tell for certain though. But the way Windows kills the processes might be different from C# to Wmi.

Comment: @Vincent: I guess what I meant to say is, I would rather this code work than do that. I have this whole system already up and running and  would rather not do remote kills as I don't have access to them "remotely".

Comment: Oh allright ! This can be done locally too without specifying a computer name. You only need powershell installed on them and you can test the kills from the command prompt.

Comment: Although you mentioned it, just to make it clear: the remote program (on clients) .EXE must be compiled with "Any CPU" (not the server). Is this what you have done? see also here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768689/c-sharp-get-path-filename-by-handle-hwnd-32-and-64bit

Comment: @SimonMourier: I can guarantee that I am using "Any CPU", I have it open right now. Although, in that SO thread you sent me, they are using GetWindowThreadProcessID, and someone commented saying that if you use that process, there are no problems, but if you do it through another exe there could be issues. I am trying to get the process info straight from my process list. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @KyleUithoven - not sure, it depends what line throws the exception.

Comment: Alright, I found which block throws the error. It happens when I am accessing the MainModule/Modules of the Process. It does NOT happen when I am trying to kill them.

Comment: It's a Win32Exception. The most vague and annoying one =D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As detailed in the comments of [the MSDN page for Process.Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx) and [this thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30803255/enumerating-modules-inside-a-process-in-a-64-bit-system.aspx) there is a known issue in `Process.Modules` when enumerating 32 bit processes from a 64 bit process and visa-versa:

> Internally .NET's Process.Modules is using function EnumProcessModules
>   from PSAPI.dll. This function has a known issue that it cannot work
>   across 32/64 bit process boundary. Therefore enumerating another
>   64-bit process from 32-bit process or vice versa doesn't work
>   correctly.

The solution seems to be to use the [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, (which must be called via P/Invoke), however this function is only available on later versions of Windows.

> We fixed this issue by adding
>   a new function called EnumProcessModulesEx to PSAPI.dll
>   (http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682633.aspx), but we
>   currently cannot use it in this case:
>
> - it only works on Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008
> - currently .NET 2.0 Framework don't have a service pack or hotfix to make Process.Modules use this new API

Comment: This is probably not the issue @Kyle is running into, because this bug will silently fail to enumerate certain modules, without throwing an exception.

Comment: Actually it does throw an exception. I have been running into the same issue with Process.Modules.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the Process.Modules. I had figured that it was most likely an issue in the .NET Framework. I will give feedback when I test the EnumProcessModulesEx Function.

Answer (score 3):

There are only some issues regarding the handling of the processes and the locking that I would change:

```
object lockObject = new object();
List<Process> processesToRemove = new List<Process>();
foreach (Process p in _runningProcesses)
{
    foreach (ProcessModule module in p.Modules)
    {
        string[] strs = text.Split('\\');

        if (module.ModuleName.Equals(strs[strs.Length - 1]))
        {
            processesToRemove.Add(p);
            break;
        }
    }                    
}                
lock (lockObject)
{
    foreach (Process p in processesToRemove)
    {                 
        p.Kill();
        _runningProcesses.Remove(p);
    }                
}
```

I'm not answering for the bounty, just wanted to give some ideas. This code isn't tested because I don't exactly know what you are trying to do there.

Just consider not to lock the process-list and to keep the lock as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sprinter252 that `_runningProcesses` should not be used as your sync object here.

```
//Somewhere that is accessible to both the thread getting the process list and the thread the 
//code below will be running, declare your sync, lock while adjusting _runningProcesses
public static readonly object Sync = new object();

IList<Process> runningProcesses;
lock(Sync)
{
    runningProcesses = _runningProcesses.ToList();
}
Process processToRemove = null;
foreach (Process p in _runningProcesses)
{
    foreach (ProcessModule module in p.Modules)
    {
        string[] strs = text.Split('\\');
        if (module.ModuleName.Equals(strs[strs.Length - 1]))
        {
            processToRemove = p;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (processToRemove != null)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (processToRemove != null)
{
    //If we've got a process that needs killing, re-lock on Sync so that we may 
    //safely modify the shared collection
    lock(Sync)
    {
        processToRemove.Kill();
        _runningProcesses.Remove(processToRemove);
    }
}
```

If this code is wrapped in a loop to continue to check `_runningProcesses` for the process you wish to kill, consider changing `processToRemove` to `processesToRemove` and change it's type to a collection, iterate over that list in the bottom block after a check for a non-zero count and lock outside of that loop to decrease the overhead of obtaining and releasing locks per process to kill.