# How to get variables from the Project referencing the library?

Tags: c#, .net, class, variables, dll

let's say i have a

```
public struct Level
    {

        public Level(int _Id)
        {
            Id = _Id;
        }

        public int Id { get; }

        public void NextLevel()
        { 
            
        }
        
    }
```

in the referenced library,
and this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Level Lvl1 = new Level(0);
            Level Lvl2 = new Level(1);
            Level Lvl3 = new Level(2);

            //some code..
            //some code..
            //some finish code..
            Level.NextLevel();
        }
```

In the project that is referencing the dll library.

now i want the NextLevel() Method from library to change from a level to another by Id, even if the variable does not exist in the library, but does in the project.

Let's say the player finishes level 1, the method is being invoked.
the method should get level 2 by the Id, and  if the level does not exist, then it should throw a custom exception.

NOTE: i am not using unity or any other C# game engine. i am making my own engine.

Comment: You may need `class Game` with collection of levels. Method `game.NextLevel()` makes more sense.

Comment: well, it does not matter, the code i have put in the question is only an example of what i would "likely" want. but i have no idea how to access variables from a referencing library.

Comment: *"how to access variables from a referencing library"* - what variable? `Id`? Since it's not static you need `Level` instance, e.g. `Lvl1.Id`. The fact what `Level` type belongs to referencing library makes no difference.

Comment: i want to say that, if library code asks the project for variable X by id, the project will give him the variable, and then project can assign it as next X.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. There is no `X`, could you be more specific what is it? Proposed `Game` class can contain property `CurrentLevel`, which all methods (located inside library) can access. If it's a public property, then you can as well access it in `Main`.

Comment: X is just an example Variable if you don't understand what Level is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't magically access the local scope variable of a class if you don't provide it.

That is you can do this:

```
public class Level
    {

        public Level(int _Id)
        {
            Id = _Id;
        }

        public int Id { get; }

        public Level NextLevel { get; set; }
        
    }
```

And then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Level Lvl1 = new Level(0);
            Level Lvl2 = new Level(1);
            Level Lvl3 = new Level(2);

            Lvl1.NextLevel = Lvl2;

            //some code..
            //some code..
            //some finish code..
            if (Level.NextLevel == null)
                // throw exception
             else
                // do stuff
        }
```

If you don't let the Level struct get the reference, then it can't know about it.

Another way to go,  would be to use persistence (database, file etc) and share data from there.

You can search the entire process memory using a method like this [Reading all process memory to find address of a string variable c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717504/reading-all-process-memory-to-find-address-of-a-string-variable-c-sharp) but it is not recommended as it does not adhere to the OOP and can lead to unexpected problems (like using unteferenced variables that will be picked from GC thus messing with the managed code.

Comment: the first code gives me errors, but changing from struct to class is fine.
i will tell when it is working.

Comment: You are quite right, I missed the struct part on my first go. It's changed now.

Comment: it did not work. i want the  next level to be in the library, not in the project.
the thing is, i don't know how to make the library be able to get Project's variables.

Comment: *"how to make the library be able to get Project's variables"* - try to give a very concrete example where you show what is variable and why you can't access it.

Comment: so, in the Library, there is some if code that when player touches finish sign (game engine is in console) the Library calls a method called NextLevel(), this method should get the next level variable by previous level's id. i don't know how to get variables from a project to a library.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood this correctly, you want a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) which contains your Level class. You then want to access that class from your game project. To do this you need to create your library project and compile your DLL file. Then add that DLL file as a reference to your game project. Then you would need to 'use the namespace' of the library I.e. `using DLLNamespace;`. Here is an example of how I would approach this:

**Class Library Project (DLL)**

I've created a `LevelManager` class which contains a `List<Level>` of available levels. The `LevelManager` instance can add new levels by calling the `CreateLevel()` method. You can then access the current level, next level and number of levels available from your game project. I've also added a property named `WhatIsNextLevel` which would allow you to retrieve the next level without loading it if you needed to for some reason.

You could alternatively use a `Dictionary<int, Level>` instead of `List<Level>` and use the key as the level's ID.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LevelLibrary
{
    public class LevelManager
    {
        public List<Level> Levels { get; set; } = new List<Level>();
        public Level CurrentLevel => Levels.Where(l => l.ID == currentLevel).FirstOrDefault();
        public Level WhatIsNextLevel => Levels.Where(l => l.ID == currentLevel + 1).FirstOrDefault(); // Get the next level without changing the current level
        public int LevelsAvailable => Levels.Count();

        private int currentLevel = 0;

        public class Level
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public Level(int id)
            {
                ID = id;
            }
        }

        public Level CreateLevel()
        {
            Level newLevel = new Level(Levels.Count + 1);
            Levels.Add(newLevel);
            if (currentLevel == 0) currentLevel = 1;

            return newLevel;
        }

        public Level NextLevel()
        {
            currentLevel++;
            return CurrentLevel;
        }

    }
}
```

**Game Project**

I've adjusted your example to create a few levels and then loop through them until you reach the end, just to show how it could be used. Instead of having a loop here to create multiple levels, you could also create a `CreateLevels(int numLevels)` method in your library and have the loop there so it can be reused else where.

```
using LevelLibrary; // Use your Class Library (DLL) namespace (Don't forget to add it as a reference)

namespace Game
{
    class Game
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LevelManager levelManager = new LevelManager();

            // Create some example levels
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                levelManager.CreateLevel();
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Starting on level {levelManager.CurrentLevel.ID.ToString()}");

            // Loop through more levels than we have just to show an example
            // of how you can change to the next level and handle null
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                levelManager.NextLevel();

                //some code..
                //some code..
                //some finish code..
                if (levelManager.CurrentLevel == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There are no more levels");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Level is now {levelManager.CurrentLevel.ID.ToString()}");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine(); // Keep the window open so you can see the output
        }
    }
}
```