# Unable to read all the requests part of the memory

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process, psapi

I ran an executable using `CreateProcess` like so:

```
CreateProcess(fname, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL,NULL, &si, pi)
```

Note the `pi` in `CreateProcess` is passed by reference.

After that, I want to read the process memory at the address of `LoadLibrary()`, so I used this code:

```
void read_mem(PROCESS_INFORMATION pi)
{
    SIZE_T bytes = 0;
    char messageBoxOriginalBytes[6] = {};
    HINSTANCE hMod = GetModuleHandle("user32.dll");
    if (!hMod)
    {
        printf("unable to locate user32.dll\n");
        return 1;
    }
    msg_func = GetProcAddress(hMod, "MessageBoxA");
    if (msg_func == NULL)
    {
        printf(" unable to locate messagebox\n");
        CloseHandle(hMod);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, msg_func, messageBoxOriginalBytes, 6, &bytes))
    {
        printf("Failed to read process memory  %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    } 
}
```

The error that I get is 299:

> Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

I did try to use `OpenProcess()` with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, but that does not seem to have an effect.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Here is a discussion of same error on stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986486/c-sharp-only-part-of-a-readprocessmemory-or-writeprocessmemory-request-was-compl   Although it is for c#, i think it may be useful -- please have a look.

Comment: @Kz2023 I did try `EnumProcessModules` but it fails

Comment: You've created a suspended process object. There's [not a whole lot](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131) in it.

Comment: @IInspectable but i want to modify the process memory before it continues execution

Comment: You cannot read (or modify) process memory that's not there yet. This doesn't change just because you want it very much.

Comment: @IInspectable how would one go about doing it then?

Comment: The alternative for sane programs is implementing a debugger and request module load events.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```cpp
CreateProcess(fname, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL,NULL, &si, pi);
```

This isn't inherently wrong, but using the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` creation flag has several consequences. Since processes are [self-initializing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131), the `CreateProcess` call does the bare minimum required for the primary thread to pick up initialization.

Notably, the kernel will not map modules (except *ntdll.dll*) into the address space. Mapping modules (and resolving imports) is the responsibility of the process' primary thread. Until that starts executing, there isn't much to be found in the process' address space.

Any attempt to read memory backed by to-be-loaded modules will thus fail.

Comment: I tried multiple approaches and all of them resulted in the same 299 error code.

Comment: @loaded_dypper You will need to ask about those issues separately. The question here is what the issue is, and this proposed answer covers that question specifically.